# Logistic regression with negative weights in Matlab

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, matlab, weights

I want to apply a logistic regression to a set of data where observations have been assigned weights depending on their "distance" from {0,1}. Most of the observations have weights within [0,1] range, but some could be outside. (I know that this means that the binomial model is not really suitable, but let's say this is a restriction I am working under). If I write out a log-likelihood for an observation as

$$w_i \ln(p(X\beta)) + (1-w_i)\ln(1-p(X\beta))$$

then this seems to work as desired: observations that have weights above 1 "pull the p" higher, and those with negative weights "pull the p" lower.

However, when I try to use this weights in Matlab's glmfit, I get a warning "Weights are ill-conditioned." The documentation in Matlab on how the weights are used is "thin" (it just says "Vector of prior weights, such as the inverses of the relative variance of each observation" without any explanation on where and how they are used in the procedure), but it seems that they are used in some other way than just to multiply the log-likelihood.

How are the weights applied in glmfit and how do I achieve the above log-likelihood?

Comment: Negative weights make little sense.  Could you explain what they are intended to reflect in terms of the probability model?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. As I mention in the post, the binomial is not really correct model here for the response variable (a gamma distribution would be mote appropriate), but I know that the expectation lies between some minimum and maximum bounds, so I am looking to model it as $E[Y] = E_{min}(X) + \delta(X\beta)*(E_{max}(X)-E_{min}(X))$ where delta is some function from X to {0,1} for which I am looking to use logit, hence I find myself using logistic regression.

Comment: But how does that work with negative weights?  It isn't at all apparent what the weights are doing or what you are hoping they will accomplish.  It's certain that Matlab is not expecting negative weights!

Comment: @whuber The weights are computed as $w_0 = \frac{E_{max} - Y_i}{E_{max} - E_{min}}$ and $w_1 = 1-w_0$ and each observation is duplicated but with response set once to 0 and the second time to 1.

Comment: @Let's forget about the negative weights for the moment. How are weights actually applied in glmfit?

Comment: According to http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/toolbox/stats/glmfit.html, the weights would multiply the contribution to the log likelihood from each observation.  That's not what your formula does.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. If I understood correctly, that means that for the observations where the response is set to 1, the likelihood is $w_i\ln(p(X\beta))$ and for those where it is set to 0, the likelihood is $w_i\ln(1-p(X\beta))$? This is what I had in mind also, but in my formula I show the total contribution from an observation: one coming from setting it to 1, and the other to 0.

Comment: No, that's not what it means: a weight applies to an observation *regardless of what its value might be.*  Thus, if $\lambda(x_i;\theta)$ would be the contribution of observation $x_i$ to the log likelihood, its weighted contribution would be $w_i\lambda(x_i;\theta).$

Comment: @whuber I think one of us is confused. In the binomial model, the log-likelihood is $LL(Y_i) =Y_i\ln(p) + (1-Y_i)\ln(1-p)$ where $Y_i  \in \{0,1\}$, so if $Y_i = 1$ then the weighted log-likelihood becomes $w_i\ln(p)$ and if $Y_i=0$ then the weighted log-likelihood becomes $w_i\ln(1-p)$. Anyway, thank you for your time and comments.